# Authenticate with Firebase using a phone number with Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I want to implement the authentication with Firebase through a phone number, I am using Angular 10 but I have this problem

> ERROR TypeError: can't access property "RecaptchaVerifier", firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3 __. Default.auth is undefined.

```js
import { FirebaseAuthServiceService } from 'src/app/services/firebase-auth-service.service';
import { WindowsService } from 'src/app/services/windows.service';
import  firebase from 'firebase/app';

export class VerificacionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

recaptchaVerifier: firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier;

constructor(  public fireAuthService: FirebaseAuthServiceService,
              public win: WindowsService
              ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.windowRef = this.win.windowRef;
  }
```

Here I call the recaptcha:

```js
   ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      size: 'normal',
      callback: (response) => { console.log(response)}
    });

    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier.reder();
  }
```

Send

```js
  send(phoneNumber: string){
    var appVerifier = this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier;

    this.fireAuthService.loginPhone(phoneNumber, appVerifier).then(res => {
       this.windowRef.confirmationResult = res;
       console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err);
    })
```

The Firebase configuration of my web application I have it in the environment.firebaseConfig and I load it like this. AngularFireModule.initializeApp (environment.firebaseConfig), in app.module.ts